# Why do event handlers need to be references and not invocations?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the [React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html), it says

> Doing `onClick={alert('click')}` would alert immediately instead of when the button is clicked.

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={() => alert('click')}>
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

However, I cannot understand why that would be... can anyone clarify this for me please? Why can't you pass a function invocation as a handler?

Comment: `alert('click')` is a function invocation. React will read it and immediately execute it. You should pass a reference to a named function instead. So, `this.myFunction` instead of `this.myFunction()`. Alternatively you can reference an anonymous function, which is what you put in your original post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you do `onClick={alert("click")}` that's going to call the `alert` function and assign the returned value (`undefined`) to the `onClick` property. So, what React sees is `onClick={undefined}` and says: *well, that's not a function, why would I add such a handler?*

What you want to pass to `onClick` is a function, not `undefined`.

Therefore, you have to do: `onClick={myFunction}` where `myFunction` can be `() => alert("...")` as you mentioned, or you can use `bind` to create a similar function:

```
onClick={alert.bind(window, "click")}
```

`bind` will *return* a **new function** which will internally call the `alert` function with the `"click"` argument.

---

A similar case is when you do `setTimeout(() => alert("after 1 second"), 1000)`. `setTimeout` expects a function. If you do `setTimeout(alert("..."), 1000)`, the `alert` will be called, indeed, but the `setTimeout` will receive as first argument `undefined` (that's what `alert` returns).

Instead, if you have a function which *returns a function*, that will work:

```
// This will be called first and will return a function
const sayHelloTo = name => {
   // This will be the function passed to `setTimeout`
   return () => alert(`Hello ${name}`);
};
setTimeout(sayHelloTo("Alice"), 1000);
```

You can use it in the same way for the `onClick` thingy:

```
onClick={sayHelloTo("Alice")}
```

---

This is a very tiny example about what happens in the background (it's just a proof of concept, I'm sure what it actually happens is way better than this):

```
const elm = {
  onClick: null,
  // The click method can be invoked manually
  // using `elm.click()` or is natively invoked by the browser
  click () {
     if (typeof this.onClick === "function") {
        this.onClick();
     }
  }
};

// If you do:
elm.onClick = alert("click"); // this calls the alert, and returns undefined
elm.onClick === undefined // true

// But when doing:
elm.onClick = () => alert("click");
typeof elm.onClick // "function"

elm.click(); // this will call the alert
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer and Andrew's one made it much clearer for me now!

Comment: This is a great answer, but would be better if it actually explained why the return value was called more in detail, which is the issue at hand.

Comment: @coffeeak Cool! Consider marking one of the answers :)

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks, tried to make that a little bit clearer. :)

Answer (score 4):

When you have an event handler *it must be a function reference*, not a function invocation. This is because internally when the handler is executed, the handler *is first evaluated* before it can be called. With inline JSX expressions such as when passing an event handler prop, the expression is **evaluated** when the component is declared, before the handler is called.

Thus, if you pass in an invocation such as `alert('click')`, it will alert as it is being evaluated. When the event is triggered and the handler is called, it will then attempt to call the return value of `alert` (which is undefined) -- not good. Instead, you need a function reference, which when evaluated gives you a callable function which is then called as the handler.

Take this pseudocode for an example:

```
function on(event, handler) {
    //some event listener function that runs the handler when event happens
    //then we call handler when the event happens:
    handler();
}
```

Imagine if we invoked the function as `on('click', alert('test'))`, then `alert('test')` would be evaluated and the return value would be passed as the handler, which is undefined. Then you would be trying to call `undefined()`, not good. Thus, you must pass a function reference, a reference to a callable function.

Comment: Thank you! Very nicely explained!