# Javascript ES6 Bind error react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Can someone explain why I keep getting an error with the following setup:

I have this statement in my constructor:

```
this.bitLink = this.bitLink.bind(this),
```

Then I have my function as follows:

```
bitLink(url){

    let bitly = new Bitly('f06707dhbt4c63f50d83735fa83bba16bcbdc41');

    bitly.shorten(JSON.stringify(url), (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Then I call my function like so:

```
<p className="shareBtn" onClick={this.bitLink(`/album/${album._id}`)}>Share!</p>
```

But when I load the page I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bitLink' of undefined
```

From what I have researched, this seems to be a proper way to give `this` the right context but it's still returning undefined.

Edit:

Full component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import actions from '../actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { APIManager } from '../utils'
import {Router, Route, Redirect, Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Image, CloudinaryContext, Transformation} from 'cloudinary-react';
import Bitly from 'bitly';



class AlbumBoard extends Component {
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        albums: []
    }
}


render(){

    const toPublicId = (image) => {
        return image.slice(62, image.length)
    }

    const bitLink = (url) => {
        let bitly = new Bitly('f06707da4944c63f50d83735fa83bba16bcbdc41');

        bitly.shorten(JSON.stringify(url), (response) => {
          console.log(response);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    return(
        <div className="albumBoard">

        {(this.props.currentUser) ?
            this.props.currentUser.albums.map(function(album, i){
                return <div key={i} className="thumbnailContainer">
                            <h2>{album.name}</h2>
                            <Link to={`/album/${album._id}`}>{album._id}</Link>
                            <p>{album.description}</p>
                            <div className="albumThumbnailContainer">
                            <CloudinaryContext cloudName="djswgrool" fetchFormat="auto">
                                    { (album.images.length < 3) ?
                                        <Image publicId={toPublicId(album.images[0].url)} responsive className="album2">
                                            <Transformation
                                                width="200"
                                                height="200"
                                                crop="fill" />
                                        </Image>
                                        :
                                        <div>
                                            <Image publicId={toPublicId(album.images[0].url)} responsive className="album1">
                                                <Transformation
                                                    width="200"
                                                    height="200"
                                                    crop="fill" />
                                            </Image>
                                            <Image publicId={toPublicId(album.images[1].url)} responsive className="album2">
                                                <Transformation
                                                    width="200"
                                                    height="200"
                                                    crop="fill" />
                                            </Image>
                                            <Image publicId={toPublicId(album.images[2].url)} responsive className="album3">
                                                <Transformation
                                                    width="200"
                                                    height="200"
                                                    crop="fill" />
                                            </Image>
                                        </div>

                                    }
                                </CloudinaryContext>
                            </div>
                            <div className="X"></div>
                            <p className="shareBtn" onClick={bitLink(`/album/${album._id}`)}>Share!</p>
                        </div>
            })
        :
            null}
        </div>
    )
}
}

const stateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    currentUser: state.account.currentUser
}
}

export default connect(stateToProps)(AlbumBoard)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do event handlers need to be references and not invocations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44371028/why-do-event-handlers-need-to-be-references-and-not-invocations)

Comment: can you show, the full component?

Comment: @JoseAPL sure, I added it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing a function reference to the `onClick` event but the value the returned from the function `bitLink`.
This is because you are invoking it

```
onClick={this.bitLink()}
```

instead of just passing the reference of it

```
onClick={this.bitLink}
```

If you want to pass a parameter to it you would need to either:
Create another wrapper function that will return and pass it the parameter:
You can do it in several ways:
currying:

```
bitLink(url){
  return function(e){
    let bitly = new Bitly('f06707dhbt4c63f50d83735fa83bba16bcbdc41');

    bitly.shorten(JSON.stringify(url), (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

or arrow function:

```
bitLink = (url) => (e){
    let bitly = new Bitly('f06707dhbt4c63f50d83735fa83bba16bcbdc41');

    bitly.shorten(JSON.stringify(url), (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

or arrow function inside the event:

```
onClick={() => {this.bitLink(url)}}
```

Note that this will make a new function instance on each render.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:
`onClink={() => this.bitLink(`/album/${album._id}`)}`